# A cycle was detected in the build path of project ... eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Just started using eclipse and I am getting the following error : A cycle was detected in the build path of project . The cycle consists of projects {x,y}.

How can i fix this? I have not done anything different, was trying to add maven dependencies when the error popped up. Have removed the decency but it still shows.  Have tried to clean/build in maven, clean and restart my eclipse.

Any suggestions? been spending hours trying to fix this

Comment: Remove the cyclical dependencies. You do understand why this happens, right? Your `x` depends on `y`, and `y` depends on `x`, so it's impossible to perform a build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move code.  It's your only option.  You need to identify code in x that depends on y or code in y that depends on x.  If you can move the code to the other project, that might fix the problem.  Otherwise, you may need to move code to a new project.  I've had to do both.

Comment: Why would the error get triggered if i made no modifications? dont understand this crappy eclipse ide -.-

Comment: @user648244 Ah, because you haven't taken the time to learn how to use Eclipse (this isn't an Eclipse issue, it's common to java development in any (or no) IDE), then it must be crappy.

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust preferences to handle these dependencies, it would give you a WARNING
`Preferences > Java > Compiler > Building > Build path problems > Circular dependencies`

This worked for me atleast ! Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this issue. For me issue was I accidentally added 1 dependency in other project pom.xml file which was not required.

Check you all pom.xml files and remove unwanted dependency.

This happened to me because, I had one error in project and clicked on that error and I clicked on "Add dependency" which will add unwanted dependency.

Hope this help someone.